# Bitmask parameter naming conventions?

Tags: c, naming-conventions

If I want to write a thread-safe method that simultaneously sets and clears some internal bits, I might do it with two arguments: a 32-bit mask of the internal bits to modify, and a 32-bit mask indicating whether to set the internal bits specified by the first parameter to 0 or 1.

What is the convention for naming these two parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of any overall standards, although many places I have worked have had naming standards, etc.

Each bit in the mask gets defined individually, for example:

```
#define TANK_GAUGE_OK (0x80)  // 1 when the gauge is properly initialized and working
#define TANK_FULL     (0x08)  // 1 when tank is filled completely
#define TANK_HIGH     (0x04)  // 1 when tank is at least 1/4 full
#define TANK_LOW      (0x02)  // 1 when tank is at least 1/8 full
#define TANK_NOTEMPTY (0x01)  // 1 when there is some fuel in tank
#define TANK_LIGHTS_MASK (TANK_FULL | TANK_HIGH | TANK_LOW | TANK_NOTEMPTY )
```

For function names --

```
SET_ON(unsigned setMask), SET_OFF(unsigned clearMask)
```

To update specific bits in a register:

```
Update(changeMask, valueMask)
```

where *changeMask* contains the bits you want to update, to 1, and *valueMask* contains the bits values you want to set.

You would use them like this code for an embedded fuel gauge monitor:

```
static unsigned short fuelGaugeRegisterValue = 0x0000;
extern unsigned short *fuelGaugeRegister;

. . .

void UpdateFuelGauge(unsigned changeMask, unsigned valueMask) {
    // code to grab mutex goes here...
    fuelGaugeRegisterValue &= (~changeMask);
    fuelGaugeRegisterValue |= ( changeMask & valueMask);
    *fuelGaugeRegister = fuelGaugeRegisterValue;
    // code to release mutex goes here...
}

. . .

void SetFuelGaugeFromLevel(unsigned byte currentLevel)
    if ( currentLevel == 0xFF ) {
        UpdateFuelGauge( TANK_LIGHTS_MASK, TANK_LIGHTS_MASK );
    }
    else if (level >= 0x03 ) {
        UpdateFuelGauge( TANK_LIGHTS_MASK, (TANK_HIGH | TANK_LOW | TANK_NOTEMPTY) );
    }
    else if (level >= 0x02 ) {
        UpdateFuelGauge( TANK_LIGHTS_MASK, (TANK_LOW | TANK_NOTEMPTY) );
    }
    else if (level > 0x01 ) {
        UpdateFuelGauge( TANK_LIGHTS_MASK, TANK_NOTEMPTY );
    }
    else {
        UpdateFuelGauge( TANK_LIGHTS_MASK, 0 );
    }
}
```

Some other notes:

Try to name the bits and standard masks in a manner that you can make an educated guess as to what the bit would mean when it is "asserted". For instance, "EMPTY_FLAG" makes you guess as to whether "1" means "empty", of "not empty".

[Wikipedia has an article on signal masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) that uses some terminology, but currently it does mention any naming conventions.

Comment: A problem with your ChangeMask() function is that it creates the possibility of setting and clearing the same bit at the same time, which doesn't make sense. Preventing that case requires DBC, which in C++ is evaluated at runtime. It would be better to make it impossible to set and clear the same bit, which is what "mask" and "value" (or whatever they're called) achieve.

Comment: @Traal -- thanks for pointing this out. You are correct. ChangeMask() was a home-grown function used in a tightly controlled state engine, but I see the problem with using this. I will edit my answer soon (unless someone beats me to it...